# Nginx return 404 not found

Tags: nginx

```
    server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        location /phpmyadmin {
            root /var/www/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

            location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                    expires max;
                    log_not_found off;
            }

            location ~* \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            }    
}
```

If I go to /phpmyadmin I get an 404 page. How to fix it? In /var/www folder exists file index.html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block

Comment: You go to `/phpmyadmin` so nginx looking for file `/var/www/phphmyadmin/index.php` (then `.html` and `.htm`)